# no open ports available when running serve for vue cli is what im requesting

Tags: vue-cli

Could somebody help me to solve a problem with the very start of my VUE cli project , cause i have tried to run serve it in order to see the App.vue but this error shows up:

`vue-cli-service serve`

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: No open ports available
Error: No open ports available
    at Server.onError (C:\Users\kikit\bookstoreapp\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:58:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at Server.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1327:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bookstoreapp@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bookstoreapp@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kikit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-29T12_40_18_509Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\kikit\bookstoreapp>
```

and the log report would be

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~preserve: bookstoreapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: bookstoreapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\kikit\bookstoreapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\bin;;C:\Users\kikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\kikit\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: CWD: C:\Users\kikit\bookstoreapp
10 silly lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bookstoreapp@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: bookstoreapp@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid bookstoreapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\kikit\bookstoreapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bookstoreapp@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bookstoreapp@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Which might be the error ?..... thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete log as provided in the file location: `C:\Users\kikit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-29T12_40_18_509Z-debug.log`

Comment: ok is full exposed